# Why does DOM update only when refreshed

Tags: javascript

I noticed that some websites do not update their DOM when you initially load them. For example, if you visit YouTube and click on a video or visit Google Play and click on an app, if you read the DOM's meta element with the name "description", you get the general description for that site. But if you refresh the page, the description updates itself with more specific description for that particular item being viewed. You also get the update if you view the page's source, although this seems to be the equivalent of doing a refresh.

I find this problematic, because my app needs to extract the description for pages but these descriptions won't show the true description until a refresh is done. And I'm certainly not going to refresh a user's page to get at that information.

I can't understand why YouTube or Google Play do this. Is this something that is part of Chrome (that I'm using) or is this update done by some javascript but manages to bypass the DOM?

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the DOM does not update when it uses Ajax to retrieve something like the description. It does seem that the javascript is responsible for updating the meta tag's "content" attribute and clearly these sites don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably they are using Ajax and the History API in order to update the page content and change the displayed URL without performing a full load of a new page. Effectively running the website as a Single Page Application.

Unfortunately, it also sounds like they aren't updating *all* of the page and are leaving the meta elements you care about untouched (probably because very few people care about them and they exist primarily for the benefit of robots).

Since the data hasn't been sent to the browser, you can't get it without making an HTTP request to fetch it.

Comment: I guess I am making the assumption that Chrome automatically updates its DOM even when an Ajax call is made. That does not appear to be the case.

Comment: @AndroidDev — It updates its DOM to whatever the JavaScript programmer said it should update it to. As mentioned in the answer, said programmer probably just didn't bother to update the meta element.